# Force node to use git bash on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, bash

I have a package.json file that looks like:

```
{
  "name": "APP",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "test": "./test/dbLoad && env db=test test=1 jasmine"
  }
}
```

When I run npm test, I get an error:

```
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I'm guessing this is because node is using windows `cmd.exe`. The command works fine if i preface it with `bash`. Can I change a configuration setting of some kind in node so that it automatically uses bash?

Answer (score 9):

Set NPM's `script-shell` to point to Git Bash (note the newer path):

`npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"`

This tells NPM to run scripts defined in your `package.json` (such as `start` or `test`) using the specified shell instead of the default, which on Windows is `cmd.exe`. See https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#script-shell.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can!

Before running `npm run` you should do:

```
set comspec=your_bash.exe_folder
```

The NPM package, check the comspec enviroment, and run it on win32.
By default `ComSpec=C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe`

For more info you can see the source code  of NPM: [lifecycle.js (Line 219)](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/lib/utils/lifecycle.js#L219)

> ```
> if (process.platform === 'win32') {
>     sh = process.env.comspec || 'cmd'
>     shFlag = '/d /s /c'
>     conf.windowsVerbatimArguments = true
>   }
> ```

You can set the environment comspec, to your bash by default by using the registry. If you need any help, please comment.

Comment: Will this change the shell for my entire system or just for when i run node?

Comment: tried typing set comspec='C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe' and it didnt stick. Also tried setting the ComSpec variable via control panel, and running `npm test` still fails with the same error.

Comment: I tried on my machine, and it's working. Did you type `set compspec=...` without the quotes? Did you see that the comspec updated? (using `set com`)

Comment: I had the same problem @RobbyAllsopp. I fixed using `export "comspec=C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe"`