# Specify which shell Yarn uses for running scripts

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, sh, yarnpkg

My `package.json` has a script in it like this:

`"buildTslint": "node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc node_modules/awesomeLibrary_node_tslint/{,helpers/}*.ts",`

Note the `{,helpers/}*.ts` part, this is called [Brace Expansion](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-brace-expansion) and is only possible in `bash`, not `sh`.

When running `yarn buildTslint` I get the following output:

```
# yarn buildTslint
yarn buildTslint v0.22.0
$ node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc node_modules/awesomeLibrary_node_tslint/{,helpers/}*.ts
error TS6053: File 'node_modules/awesomeLibrary_node_tslint/{,helpers/}*.ts' not found.
error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

**It seems that Yarn uses `sh` to execute these scripts, but I'd like to use `bash` for this, to be able to use brace expansion.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may launch the command using `system` function see also `man 3 system`.

To see which system call is used :

```
strace yarn ...
```

`system` uses `fork`+`exec`+`wait` and the exec family functions uses shell `/bin/sh`

to use bash the command can be changed to `bash -c 'command ..'`

Comment: `bash -c 'command ..'` works as expected, thanks a lot. Is there any way to set the default shell, though, so this won't happen in the future?

Comment: I think not if it's done through system call by yarn it is implementation specific, and since the `man 3 exec` `man 3 system` specify `/bin/sh`

Answer (score 33):

yarn version [1.19 added support](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/commit/a2a054438fe91f9860dd06cc4ee7b8004ad7efa0) for a new config parameter `script-shell`. You can now do the following:

```
yarn config set script-shell /bin/bash
```

Comment: To reset `yarn config delete script-shell`

Comment: To make yarn use Powershell (run the command from Powershell): `yarn config set script-shell (Get-Command powershell.exe).Definition`

Comment: Where is the official documentation, couldn't find this in the v1 doc.

Comment: You saved me today, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yarn doesn't yet provide a way to configure the default shell used for running scripts, see: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4248

However, since yarn uses Node for spawning its processes, you can work around that by changing the default shell that Node itself uses.

On Ubuntu, if you have root permissions, you can do this by changing the symlink `/bin/sh` to point to something other than `dash`:

`sudo ln -sf /bin/bash /bin/sh`

In Git-bash in Windows, you can change the `COMSPEC` environment variable to something other than `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`, but I haven't gotten that to work for me.

See also:

- [Force node to use git bash on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35462422/force-node-to-use-git-bash-on-windows)

Comment: The issue that you link to was fixed in early 2018 \o/
https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4248#issuecomment-354689418
So I think `yarn config set script-shell bash` should work