# Yarn cannot execute source command

Tags: node.js, linux, yarnpkg, package.json, nvm

I want to run NVM command before running the Node JS app. But when I want to execute the `source` command, the following error occurs:

**Inside `package.json` file:**

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh; nvm use 14.15.1"
  },
}
```

**Output after run `yarn run prestart` command:**

```sh
yarn run v1.22.5
$ source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh; nvm use 14.15.1
/bin/sh: 1: source: not found
/bin/sh: 1: nvm: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

What should I do? Although `source` and `nvm` command is working fine outside of Yarn.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use the \bin\bash to run these commands instead of \bin\sh.

Check this answer to change the default shell for yarn.

[Specify which shell Yarn uses for running scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778649/specify-which-shell-yarn-uses-for-running-scripts)

Comment: Can you give an example I've visited the link you provided but still don't understand.

Comment: To change the default shell that yarn run commands by issuing `yarn config set script-shell /bin/bash`. To revert back issue `yarn config delete script-shell`.
Maybe /bin/sh does not have access to source command. So try with /bin/bash